# Yarn serve error command failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to run the command "yarn serve" on console for my angular project(cd/project)
However I am getting this error :

yarn run v1.17.3

$ concurrently "ng serve" "server/node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev server/server.ts"

[0] The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

[0] ng serve exited with code 1

[1] Using ts-node version 8.3.0, typescript version 3.6.2

[1] hello

[1] server/node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev server/server.ts exited with code 0

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not in the right directory. Make sure you are in the same directory as your `angular.json` file.

Comment: Glad to hear that, you could accept the answer so the issue gets closed. Happy coding!